# How to request screen lock on ios

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a flutter app that can request screen lock on Android device using method channel & device policy manager. How to do it on iOS? is it possible if I using Screen Time API? (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336)

Comment: It is not possible for an app to lock the device on iOS.